# Symbolic FindInstance

Tags: equation-solving

I'm wondering if there is any way of doing something like the following:
`FindInstance[x < y, {x}, Reals]` and getting, as a possible return value, `{x -> y - 1}`.

Currently `FindInstance` will complain that y is a non-constant expression..

Comment: I am assuming you would not be satisfied with `FindInstance[x - y < 0, {x, y}, Reals]` (* {x->0,y->1} *)

Comment: At this point, I think that I will just implement a function which uses `CylindricalDecomposition`.  If I do successfully do that, I'll post it as an answer here.